# Extending a line by dragging another object in a figure

Tags: matlab, object, line, drag, figure

I have the functions for moving objects around in a figure. The figure is also populated by lines. I'm trying to attach one vertex to an object (or a position fixed relative to the object) so that when I drag that object, the line extends with it. I wouldn't have trouble doing this, but the imline(.) function returns a line with no 'Position' property. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get and set the position of the underlying line graphic object using the `getPosition` and `setPosition` methods of the [imline object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imline.html). These should suffice to update the line as you drag the attached object.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of that feature of imline(.).